# weird Java threadpool behavior - losing tasks unless Futures are used

Tags: java, debugging, threadpool, future, callable

I am creating a threadpool and since I don't need any output from my threads, I am not using Futures&Callables. But the problem is that if I don't use Futures, I am seeing that threadpool is loosing tasks that I am submitting.

Here is my code structure which is loosing tasks-

```
while(hasWorkToDo){
ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(new Worker());
System.out.println("Work submitted");
}
```

Within Worker(), I am printing "got work" at the very first line of run() implementation.

When I run above code the number of "got work" is always less than "Work submitted".

But, when I change my code structure to below-

```
ArrayList<Future<String>> list = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
while(hasWorkToDo){
Future<String> submit=ThreadPoolExecutor.submit(new Worker());
list.add(submit) 
}

for (Future<String> f : list) {
f.get();
}
```

I then see that number of times "got work" is equal to "Work submitted"

This leads me to believe that unless I am using Futures&Callables, the threadpool is using tasks that I am submitting.

Have you seen such behavior before? Is there a better way to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You con't need to keep the Future tasks, less you need to wait for them to complete before shutting down the executor. I suspect you are using shutdownNow() somewhere. Try using shutdown() instead.

Answer (score 0):

A `ThreadPoolExecutor` may reject tasks if it is shutdown or if it has reached it's capacity. You can use [`setRejectedExectutionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setRejectedExecutionHandler%28java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler%29) to test if tasks are being rejected.